# oracle error inserting into clob - ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I have written a procedure in oracle , which reads xmltype column from a oracle table minf , converting xmltype to clob and then inserting to another table as a clob column . I get error  **ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount** . Any inputs .

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    PRD_DEV_4617_MP_TANMAYPA01.ZZZ_CLOB();   
END;



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  prd_dev_4617_MP_TANMAYPA01.zzz_clob AS 
    x clob;
    num NUMBER;
    BEGIN 
    SELECT m.xml_msg.getClobVal()  INTO x FROM minf m  WHERE rownum < 2  ; 
    FOR num IN 1..100 LOOP
       INSERT INTO ZZZ ( y) VALUES ( x); 
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT ;
    END ;
```

Comment: you are getting the output of getclobval into x and where rownum < 2 is giving you 1 row. What is the meaning of the for loop ?? where the `y` is coming from ?

Comment: y is column of ZZZ table . datatype of y is CLOB.

Comment: set up a test CASE with create table, test data, expected output

Comment: Try to use [`xmlserialize`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb13gen.htm#GUID-55FE9CED-5B25-4DA2-9F9E-921DF8276EB8): `xmlserialize(document m.xml_msg as clob)` instead of [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/changes.htm#GUID-27F902E7-911D-49A4-8FAA-BAABB5821E91) `getClobVal`.

Comment: @astentx SELECT XMLSerialize ( document m2.xml_msg AS clob) FROM MINF m2 works as standalone . let me try running procedure.

Comment: same error  .SQL Error [22993] [99999]: ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount using xmlserialize when procedure is run.